# How to solve this initial boundary value problem for heat conduction equation?

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to solve the following PDE:

```
heqn=D[u[x,t],t]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}]-D[u[x,t],{x,1}];
```

with the initial conditions:

```
ic=u[x,0]==Piecewise[{{x,0<= x<= 0.5},{1-x,0.5<= x<= 1}}];
```

and boundary conditions:

```
bc={u[0,t]== 0,u[1,t]== 0};
```

I want to get the analytic solution,but when I use `DSolve` :

```
sol=DSolve[{heqn,bc,ic},u[x,t],{x,t}]
```

there's return nothing.I am wondering how to get the analytic solution?

Comment: _v12.3_ and _v13.1_ find the solution without difficulty, which version are you in?

Comment: Mathematica gives an infinite sum as solution. I tried, in vain, to plot the solution, doesn't evaluate!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann How did you try? Something like `approxsol=u[x,t]/.sol[[1]]/.Infinity->20//Activate; Plot3D[approxsol,{x,0,1},{t,0,1},PlotRange->All]` should work. (This solution is mentioned in document of `DSolve` BTW. )

Comment: Thanks: `//Activate` solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs are fine, maybe just wait for a few more seconds or so and the output will appear because it worked for me.

When using your inputs

```
In[75]:= heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[u[x, t], {x, 1}];
ic = u[x, 0] == Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x <= 0.5}, {1 - x, 0.5 <= x <= 1}}];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0};
sol = DSolve[{heqn, bc, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

The ouput came as

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Works for me as well, (After I deleted the "In[75]:=" ).
It took  4.1 seconds on my 2.4GHz i9. (Mathematica Version 12.3 on Windows 10)

Comment: My version is 12.0,could it be that version too low?